# crontab -e is running my python script but its saving the results of the script in my home directory

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi

I've got a python script that takes data from some XML files and displays them on a website. The script overwrites the index.html file each time it's run and replaces some text in a HTML template with data stored in some variables. The script works fine.

I put the command in crontab to run every hour, and it works. But it saves the new updated index.html file to the home directory but I want it saved to /var/www/html/. The python script is running from the same location.

Is there a way I can have crontab run the script and save the index.html file the script generates to the correct location? (/var/www/html)

This is the command I've put in crontab:

```
0 * * * * python /var/www/html/boinc.py
```

Thanks

Comment: Command part can be `cd /var/www/html && python ./boinc.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of the script is irrelevant to its execution. When `cron` runs a job it sets the current directory to the home directory of the user.

You need to set the working directory yourself, or else modify your script to write to the correct place.

Comment: Thank you, I just changed the location in the script where index.html is saved. Actually quite simple in the end. haha. I'm new to python and Linux. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You must always be mindful of `cron`'s characteristics. Many assume that just because it's their user's `crontab`, that `cron` also inherits their user *environment* from the interactive shell. But this isn't how it works.

If you're ever *curious* about the environment used to run your `cron` jobs, create this simple job in your `crontab`, and `cron` will tell you what its environment is:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/printenv > /home/me/mycronenv.txt 2>&1
```

You can stop that job as soon as you get an answer by editing your `crontab` again. :)